# OSX Mountain Lion Cloud 9 install instructions

Tags: macos, cloud9-ide

How can I install cloud9 locally on osx mountain lion?

following the instructions at https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/ did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out:

Using

node --version = v0.10.5

npm --version = 1.2.18

1. npm install cloud9
2. edit node_modules/cloud9/bin/cloud9.js

   goto line 42

   where: require("cloud9").main(options);

   change to: require("../server/cloud9").main(options);
3. ./node_modules/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh

Haven't found any errors yet, but only just started using it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your nodejs version `node --version`. Use a version lower than 0.8.x

If you are already using 0.10.x and don't intend to go backwards, then you should try nvm:

- curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
- open a new terminal window (or do a shell logout + login)
- nvm install 0.8
- nvm use 0.8

Then follow cloud9 instructions

- git clone https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git
- cd cloud9
- npm install

If this doesn't work try updating npm by executing `npm update -g`

NOTE: if you get EACCES errors then you should probably try `sudo npm update -g`

Comment: Why does node need to be lower than 0.8.x?

Comment: cloud9 installation requieres `node-waf` and it was removed in version 0.9.1 (http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/08/28/node-v0-9-1-unstable/).